# How to Build & Deploy selective modules in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Actually, in our application we have around 8 modules(lazy loaded), each are being worked by individual team. Now team just want to build & deploy their own module only. How can we achieve that in Angular4?
We are using Angular-cli(prod & aot) for building/packaging the application.

Comment: you want to deploy them separately?

Comment: No, I want to deploy in the same server but I want to deploy each chunk independently. Means, if I have 8 chunks and the code has been changed in 4 modules,then instead of building and deploying all 8 modules, I want to build & deploy only 4.

Comment: hi there, did you find any solution for this? we are also looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you update angular, with new cli they provide an option to create libraries, you can push each module in a separate library and with help of ng-packagr you can create an npm package of each module(library). You can also use nrwl workspace which makes this process really easy